# How to use ngFor to access multiple object's value that is inside one big object in an HTML file?

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

In angular , I am trying to use `*ngFor` in html file to access nested objects value . The object `serverData` I try to access is as followed.

```
{//whole object i try to loop through and access
  "0": {//inner , nested object that store the data I want to access 
    "District_en": "Sha Tin",
    "Name_en": "This will be the new name",
    "Address_en": "Kwei Tei Street, Fo Tan, Sha Tin",
    "Facilities_en": "2 barbecue pits",
  },
  "1": {
    "District_en": "Sha Tin",
    "Name_en": "Lok Shun Path Barbecue Area",
    "Address_en": "Lok Shun Path, Sha Tin",
    "Facilities_en": "6 barbecue pits",
  }
}
```

I am trying to print out each attributes specifically inside each "index" object.
With following code in html. Like loop through whole object and print out each property value.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let index of serverData |  keyvalue ">
     <td>{{index.value.District_en}}</td>
     <td>{{index.value.Name_en}}</td>
     <td>{{index.value.Address_en}}</td>
     <td>{{index.value.Facilities_en}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Yet error `Object is of type 'unknown'` comes up.
I was finding similar question, but most are about accessing multiple object.
My brain stop working when it turns into the situation of multiple object inside a single object ...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface ServerData {
  District_en: string;
  Name_en: string;
  Address_en: string;
  Facilities_en: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  serverData: Record<string, ServerData>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serverData = {
      //whole object i try to loop through and access
      '0': {
        //inner , nested object that store the data I want to access
        District_en: 'Sha Tin',
        Name_en: 'This will be the new name',
        Address_en: 'Kwei Tei Street, Fo Tan, Sha Tin',
        Facilities_en: '2 barbecue pits',
      },
      '1': {
        District_en: 'Sha Tin',
        Name_en: 'Lok Shun Path Barbecue Area',
        Address_en: 'Lok Shun Path, Sha Tin',
        Facilities_en: '6 barbecue pits',
      },
    };
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let index of serverData | keyvalue">
  <td>{{ index.value.District_en }}</td>
  <td>{{ index.value.Name_en }}</td>
  <td>{{ index.value.Address_en }}</td>
  <td>{{ index.value.Facilities_en }}</td>
</tr>
```

It is rendering properly on UI

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9whew8)

Let me know if you have any doubt.

**Note: Updated ts code**

Comment: It some how still not working in my end ...  could it be the issue that i declare serverData like this ? serverData!:any;

Comment: <td>{{index.value.District_en}}</td>
"District_en" is highlighted in the debug

Comment: I have updated my code , check now

Comment: It works now , even though it has the initialize error , its probably the issue to strict type thing in option , so I quick fix it undefined and it works . Seems like the interface is the essence of this solution .